# Dependent drop box

Tags: php, html, forms

I see a lot of posts kind of around this idea but many of them revert to javascript or they are referencing just a standard drop down list. I have created a php function that generates drop-downs based on a select query in my database. Right now that part works fine but I want the one drop-box to be dependent on the other one as they are selecting makes and models of cars. Here's what I have:

```
function make(){
    $qmake = mysql_query( "SELECT VMakeID, VMake FROM vmake");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($qmake)){
        echo '<option value="' . $record['VMakeID'] . '">' . $record['VMake'] . '</option>';
    }
}

function model(){
    $qmodel = mysql_query( "SELECT VModelID, VModel FROM vmodel");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($qmodel)){
        echo '<option value="' . $record['VModelID'] . '">' . $record['VModel'] . '</option>';
    }
}
```

How do I make the "Model" function have it's select query dependent on the "Make" query without using AJAX or Javascript?? So far nothing I've found will give me a straight answer so I'm at a stopping point here.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't - without using Javascript.  You *could* look up tutorials in cascading navigation menus (implementations exist in HTML5 and CSS3) and see if you you could tweak them for your purpose, but dependant selects aren't part of HTML.

Comment: Which then begs the question - why no javascript?

Comment: My only reason for no javascript is because I'm really just not familiar with it. If I have to use that I can but it's just not something I have done anything with.

Comment: In which case - if @DavidNormington's answer doesn't do what you need then you should look at Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HTML select using `optgroup`:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Ford">
        <option value="Ford Focus">Focus</option>
        <option value="Ford Transit">Transit</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Citroen">
        <option value="Citroen C1">C1</option>
        <option value="Citroen C3">C3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This makes the dependancy between Make and Model clear and unavoidable.

Comment: Wouldn't that require me to not use the MySQL query then?

Comment: No, you used the results of the SQL query to build that select element.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm very much a php/coding noob so I'm not sure I follow. Thanks!